# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 using Route::post()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I understand that this is a common issue with Laravel 5.x, but my particular run-in with the problem is **not through submitting a form.**
Instead, I am using postman to send data to a URL endpoint to test if data is successfully received. I'm working with Laravel 5.2 and I'm very much new to it!

Here is my `routes.php` file (related content)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@buildcart');
});
```

Here is my CartController.php (entire file)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function buildcart(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

As simple as that is, when I use postman to send random data to the /cart URL, I get

`TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`

Can anyone help me understand why this is failing? I don't see how using

```
{{ csrf_token() }}
```

is the solution for this case since the data is coming from an external source.

Running list of things I've tried

- Removing the route from `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {`
- using `Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf', ['middleware' => 'web']), function () {`

Comment: What Laravel version? try to add `web` middleware.

Comment: @Rifki Laravel 5.2. How do I add the web middleware? link to tutorial?

Comment: if you are using postman(development pphase) i think you should disable the csrf from your App\kernel.php , or you can add before csrf in your route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add the route to this route group

```
  Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf', ['middleware' => 'web']), function () {

 Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@buildcart');

 });
```

**EDIT :** try to comment this line in app\kernel.php

```
   protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //       \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Comment: when you start using forms and go in ptofuction phase, you better uncomment that for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the middleware in the `routes.php` file. I think, you are getting the error as you are not authorized to use the route. Try this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::post('/cart', 'CartController@buildcart');
});
```

Comment: he said token missmatch